# implict type conversion between int and string

Tags: c++, string, implicit

How to prevent this implicit type conversion between int and std::string, which is very bug prone.
Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s="string";
    s = 123456789;  //assign a int value to std::string
    cout << s;
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

The code above can be compiled with no warning, and the result is obvious not what the coder intended. Can this be avoided?

Update: `123456789` will cause overflow warning if `-Wall` flag is set. But if I changed into `s = 98`, there will be no warning anymore. but I actually want the string to be the string `98`, not the ascii `b` character. How to prevent this then?

Comment: which compiler are you using ? I get a warning with my g++4.7

Comment: This is why we always compile with warnings enabled and take notice of them: `warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 123456789 to 21 [-Wconstant-conversion]
    s = 123456789;`

Comment: Tell us the compiler you're using.

Comment: Sorry, folks, the server gcc suite is very out-dated, its version is `g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you'd want a warning if something like this occurred. For that, you should enable all warnings. Add the `-Wall -Wextra` flag while compiling.

However, you shouldn't need these flags in this particular case. If you haven't disabled warnings, you should get an `implicit type conversion` warning.

As mentioned in comments, to enable a warning specifically for this case, you could use the `-Wconstant-conversion` flag.

Comment: Or more specifically: `-Wconstant-conversion`

Comment: @PaulR : Thank you for that. Didn't know that before.

Comment: Seems that `-Wconstant-conversion` is not supported on my old-dated compiler.

Comment: @richard.g what about `-Wall` and `-Wextra`? They should also get the job done.